# How to change h2 db password?

Tags: wso2

i can’t change a password for H2 db. I tried to do it with command:

```
chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB" --db-driver org.h2.Driver --db-username ... --db-password ... --username ... --new-password ...
```

When i start the command, it ends successfully. 
But password are not changed. 
IS doesn't start with a new password, it starts with an old password. 
How to change a password for H2 db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 product provided "chpasswd.sh" script is to change the admin password of the product and it has nothing to do with h2 database password.

If you are trying to change the H2 database password you will have to login to h2 console and update the db user password. Following are the steps.

You can download the h2 console form[1]. After that unzip it and go to h2/bin folder. Then start h2 console with below command.

```
sh h2.sh
```

Now you can access the h2 console in the browser (http://localhost:8082) and access the db with db path and current credentials. Then run the below SQL to update the DB password.

```
ALTER USER wso2carbon SET PASSWORD 'NEW_PASSWORD'
```

After this change the WSO2 product will not start due to the db password update. You will have to update the db password in "repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml" file.

Also, it is important to mention that H2 is not recommended for WSO2 products in production use.

[1] http://www.h2database.com/h2-2017-06-10.zip

Comment: i try to change not admin user password of WSO2 IS, i try to change H2 Database password

Comment: chpasswd script is to change the admin password and it has nothing to do with h2 database password. To change the H2 database password you will have to login to h2 console and try to run alter user set password option. http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_user_set_password

Comment: Updated the answer for the h2 db password change requirement.

Comment: I changed passwords on IS and API-M servers. I uncommented <H2DatabaseConfiguration> in carbon.xml file, after that i could connect to H2 configuration of WSO2 by web, i didn't launch H2 console.                                    
But i can't connect to H2 on EI and BPS servers. I do the same steps, but it doesn't work. I uncommented <H2DatabaseConfiguration> in carbon.xml file, but i can't connect to H2 configuration by web, I can connect to it through H2 console, but H2 console creates other DB files and doesn't change H2 passwords in WSO2 H2 DBs.     What is wrong?

Comment: Check the DB file name which you used in H2 console is correct. For example, if you use "WSO2CARBON_DB.h2.db" instead of "WSO2CARBON_DB" it will fail. Also if the DB file is locked by another process it may fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one command from the followings to change the admin user password of the H2 database.

```
sh chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB" --db-driver "org.h2.Driver" --db-username "wso2carbon" --db-password "wso2carbon" --username "admin" --new-password "admin123"

sh chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB" --username "admin" --new-password "admin123"
```

If you still face the same issue, mention the WSO2 product and the product version which you are trying to change the admin password.

Comment: I used this command, it didn't help.   As i wrote when i start the command, it ends successfully.    Then i change password in repository/conf/security/master-datasource.xml for WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSOAM_DB, WSO2_MB_STORE_DB. IS starts with error: wrong username or password. IS doesn't start with a new password, it starts with an old password. I use IS 5.6.0

Comment: I have no chpasswd.sh , I guess that is WSO specific and not for H in general

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are following this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Changing+User+Passwords+in+the+Carbon+Database). Please note that this is only used when you don't know the admin password and need to reset it. If you know the current password, you may just follow [this](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2torial-changing-passwords-in-wso2).

By default, WSO2 IS comes with a LDAP userstore. You can check the active userstore by checking "UserStoreManager" at [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml. More info [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+the+Primary+User+Store).

If it is JDBC, you have to find the relevant DB from the [IS_HOME]/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml by checking the dataSource name in user-mgt.xml and follow the steps in [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Changing+User+Passwords+in+the+Carbon+Database).

If it is LDAP, you may have to change the password by connecting to that ldap via a tool like Apache Directory Studio.

Comment: Yes, i tried to use an official document to change password & yenlo guide, but it didn't help.