# Update username & password of h2 database and restore earlier backups

Tags: java, h2, in-memory-database, h2db

The current credentials of my H2 database is very weak and I have been asked to change it to a complex one. There are so many backups (*.db files) which are already created with my old credentials. When I try to retrieve the backups with new credentials in my Java application, I get error as ,

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
```

When I put back my old credentials, everything works fine. What are the possible ways that I could read the backups, created with my old credentials ?

I already referred a similar question here : [how to reslove wrong username and password error in h2 database and springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064448/how-to-reslove-wrong-username-and-password-error-in-h2-database-and-springboot)

Comment: Look to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908887/how-to-change-h2-db-password

Comment: @Daniel : The link has only the normal SQL command to update the password(also looks remaining steps are for WSO). My case is that the existing H2 DB password is replaced in Java application and I want to read the h2 backups created with old credentials.

Comment: I mean , I just need to update the weak password of H2 Database to a strong password in my Java application

Comment: Please refer to my answer here stackoverflow.com/a/74924258/398348